# CSS: How to set up border radius cross browser (only IE8 and IE9 missing ?)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, border, internet-explorer-10

I have created my own buttons and set up some simple border radius.

So far I have the following which works fine for me in newer browsers but I am **not sure what I have to add here to cover IE8 and IE9** as well (I am not interested in older versions).

**Can someone tell me if I need to add or change anything else here to cover common browsers ?**
I would like to support newer versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari + IE (incl. IE8 and IE9).
Would "`-ms-...`" be required here for IE10 and "`-o-...`" for Opera ?
I do not want to cover Netscape and Konqueror (unless someone recommends this).

**My CSS:**

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Safari */
-webkit-appearance: none;               
border-radius: 5px;
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: `border-radius` works as is in most [current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) you no longer need to use browser prefixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cover IE8 in pure CSS, because it does not support neither final nor vendor-prefixed implementation. IE9 will support it just fine.

You can see full support table here:

http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

So based on this table, to answer your question, you won't need -ms-... for IE10 and -o-.. for Opera.

Comment: Thanks for that ! Does the above cover the rest then, i.e. FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE from IE9 ?

Comment: you only need  `border-radius: 5px;` to cover all those browsers

Comment: @Wojciech Maj: Thanks for the update - that's exactly what I was looking for. Will accept as soon as I can. :)

Comment: @Pythonic1: Thanks - so I don't even need the -moz-... and -webkit-... anymore ? Was that only for very old browser versions ?

Comment: Absolutely. If I were you I'd just type border-radius, without vendor prefixes at all, unless you really, really want to support Firefox 3.6 and older (0.06% of users) or Chrome 4 (0.01% of users), then you could leave -moz- and -webkit-. -ms- and -o- weren't really a thing.

Comment: @WojciechMaj: Perfect - now, I definitely don't want to support them so will leave it out then. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem :) Please mark the answer if I answered your question, don't hestitate to ask more if needed. :)

Comment: @WojciechMaj: Sure, I was about to do that but it is blocked for a couple of minutes. Will do as soon as possible. :)